# Quasar popup calendar to show current date

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

I need a little help with getting a Quasar vue  popup `q-date` to default to show the current date.  I can hard coded any date and it works fine but I can't get it to work for a variable of current date.  I have a small sample code at

```html
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-pa-md" style="max-width: 300px">
    <q-input filled v-model="date" mask="##/##/####" :rules="[checkDate]">
      <template v-slot:append>
        <q-icon name="event" class="cursor-pointer">
          <q-popup-proxy ref="qDateProxy" transition-show="scale" transition-hide="scale">
            <q-date v-model="date" @input="() => $refs.qDateProxy.hide()"  mask="MM/DD/YYYY"></q-date>
          </q-popup-proxy>
        </q-icon>
      </template>
    </q-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/morgenweck/pen/abNbNrX?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fquasar.dev%2F)

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what I needed.
I had to add

```
 beforeMount(){
  this.getCurrentDate();
},
```

and in the getCurrentDate I had to set

```
  this.date = Today;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put getCurrentDate method to data's date value for default.

Comment: if I put getCurrentDate in the html at Codepen it works but in my code it won't compile.  Can you give a little more detail?  Thanks

Comment: You should put this.getCurrentDate() ,not this.getCurrentDate because that is a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <q-date
    v-model="date"
    minimal
  />
```

and place this in the script
**date: Date.now()**

Answer (score 0):

<q-date **today-btn** v-model="date" @input="() => $refs.qDateProxy.hide()"  mask="MM/DD/YYYY" >